# Making a slider without recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Given the following jsFiddle, how can I implement the same effect as I have made without building on the stack?

http://jsfiddle.net/YWMcy/1/

I tried doing something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    (function ($) {

        function validateOptions(options) {
            if (typeof(options.delay) == typeof(0)) {
                $.error('Delay value must an integer.');
                return false;
            } else if (options.delay < 0) {
                $.error('Delay value must be greater than zero.');
                return false;
            }

            if (typeof(options.direction) == typeof('')) {
                $.error('Direction value must be a string.');
                return false;
            } else if (!(options.direction in ['left', 'right', 'up', 'down'])) {
                $.error('Direction value must be "left", "right", "up", or "down".');
                return false;
            }

            if (typeof(options.easing) == typeof('')) {
                $.error('Easing value must be a string.');
                return false;
            }

            if (typeof(options.selector) == typeof('')) {
                $.error('Selector value must be a string.');
                return false;
            }

            if (options.transition < 0) {
                $.error('Transition value must be greater than zero.');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        var methods = {
            init:   function (options) {

                return this.each(function () {

                    var settings = {
                        delay:      5000,
                        direction:  'left',
                        easing:     'swing',
                        selector:   '*',
                        transition: 3000
                    };

                    if (options) {
                        $.extend(settings, options);
                    }

                    $(this).css({
                        overflow:   'hidden',
                        position:   'relative'
                    });

                    var styles = {
                        left:       0,
                        position:   'absolute',
                        top:        0
                    };

                    switch (settings.direction) {
                    case 'left':
                        styles.left = $(this).width() + 'px';
                        break;
                    case 'right':
                        styles.left = -$(this).width() + 'px';
                        break;
                    case 'up':
                        styles.top = $(this).height() + 'px';
                        break;
                    case 'down':
                        styles.top = -$(this).height() + 'px';
                        break;
                    default:
                        jQuery.error('Direction ' + settings.direction + ' is not valid for jQuery.fn.cycle');
                        break;
                    }

                    $(this).children(settings.selector).css(styles).first().css({
                        left:   0,
                        top:    0
                    });

                    if ($(this).children(settings.selector).length > 1) {
                        $(this).cycle('slide', settings);
                    }
                });
            },

            slide:  function (options) {
                return this.each(function () {

                    var settings = {
                        delay:      5000,
                        direction:  'left',
                        easing:     'swing',
                        selector:   '*',
                        transition: 3000
                    }, animation, property, value;

                    if (options) {
                        $.extend(settings, options);
                    }

                    switch (settings.direction) {
                    case 'left':
                        animation = {left: '-=' + $(this).width()};
                        property = 'left';
                        value = $(this).width();
                        break;
                    case 'right':
                        animation = {left: '+=' + $(this).width()};
                        property = 'left';
                        value = -$(this).width();
                        break;
                    case 'up':
                        animation = {top: '-=' + $(this).height()};
                        property = 'top';
                        value = $(this).height();
                        break;
                    case 'down':
                        animation = {top: '+=' + $(this).height()};
                        property = 'top';
                        value = -$(this).height();
                        break;
                    default:
                        jQuery.error('Direction ' + settings.direction + ' is not valid for jQuery.fn.cycle');
                        break;
                    }

                    $(this).children(settings.selector + ':first-child').each(function () {
                        $(this).delay(settings.delay);
                        $(this).animate(
                            animation,
                            settings.transition,
                            settings.easing,
                            function () {
                                $(this).css(property, value);
                            }
                        );
                    });

                    $(this).append($(this).children(settings.selector + ':first-child').detach());

                    $(this).children(settings.selector + ':first-child').each(function () {
                        $(this).delay(settings.delay);
                        $(this).animate(
                            animation,
                            settings.transition,
                            settings.easing,
                            function () {
                            $(this).parent().cycle('slide', settings);
                            }
                        );
                    });
                });
            }
        };

        jQuery.fn.cycle = function (method, options) {
            if (methods[method]) {
                return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
                return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.fn.cycle');
            }
        };
    }(jQuery));

    jQuery('.slider').cycle();

});
```

But the `each()` method does not take into account nodes that are added during the loop.

Comment: i still don't know what exactly you're trying to do? as i understand it, you don't want the slide effect if there's only one slide inside the slider? then just check the slider.children().length ?

Comment: Simply put, I want the slides to cycle. Forget that I mentioned any rules about when it can/can't cycle. The focus of the question is how to obtain the same effect without adding a function call to the stack each time. I was wondering if there is some way I can implement it with a `while (true)` loop or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

You can launch your `_cycle()` function through `setInterval()`, to periodically update the slider:

```
setInterval(function() {
  _cycle2(slider, transition_duration, easing);
}, delay_duration);
```

Note that I renamed your original `_cycle()` function to `_cycle2()`, and removed the `delay_duration` parameter. You can [see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/YWMcy/4/).

Comment: What if the user wants to use `setInterval()` for something. In my experience, having multiple `setInterval()`s behaves strangely. Maybe I wasn't doing it quite right. But I couldn't stop both "intervals". I could only stop the most recently set one.

Comment: setInterval returns a value you can catch. For example: my_interval = setInterval(function() { ... If you save this value (i.e. in a global scope) you can easily stop only this interval by doing clearInterval(my_interval). This will only stop (clear) this interval, not any other you or other module has launched. An example here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: Tyler, is this the solution you are looking for? If not, please, explain why. Thanks

Comment: sorry, I haven't forgotten about this. I'm really really busy right now so I haven't had time to test it. I'll get it down tomorrow or the day after. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want anything resembling while(true).

Your problem stems from the fact that you're creating a static function and then trying to figure out how to animate the children with the constraint of keeping it all in scope of your static function.

You should instead create an instance of an object per element, let the object maintain the state of the slider and have it update that state via an implementation necessary for the slider to operate.

http://jsfiddle.net/qjVJF/3/

```
    (function ($) {
    var $b = $.behaviors || {};

    $b.slider = function(element, options) {
        this.element = $(element);
        this.panels = this.element.find('.slide');
        this.options = $.extend({}, $b.slider.defaults, options);

        this.currentPanel = 0;
        var horizontal = (this.options.direction == 'left' || this.options.direction == 'right');
        var anti = (this.options.direction == 'left' || this.options.direction == 'up');
        var distance  = horizontal ? '600' : '150';

        this.action = anti ? '-='+distance : '+='+distance;
        this.origin = anti ? distance : 0-distance;
        this.edge = horizontal ? 'left' : 'top';
        this.animation = horizontal ? { "left": this.action } : { "top" : this.action };

        this.panels.css(this.edge, this.origin+'px').show().first().css(this.edge, '0px');

        this.delayNext();
        return this;
    }
    $b.slider.defaults = {
        delay:      500,
        direction:  'left',
        easing:     'swing',
        transition: 3000
    };

    $b.slider.prototype = {
        delayNext: function() {
            setTimeout($.proxy(this.slideNext, this), this.options.delay);
        },
        slideNext: function() { 
            var current = this.panels[this.currentPanel % this.panels.length]; 
            var next = $(this.panels[++this.currentPanel % this.panels.length])
                .css(this.edge, this.origin+'px'); 

            var plugin = this;
            next.add(current).animate(
                this.animation,
                this.options.transition, 
                this.options.easing, 
                function() { 
                    if (this == current) plugin.delayNext();
                }
            );
        }  
    };

    $.fn.cycle = function (options) {
            return this.each(function() { 
                    $(this).data('bCycle', new $b.slider(this, options));
                });
    };
    }(jQuery));

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.slider').cycle();
    });
```

Comment: You, sir, are using featured in JavaScript and jQuery that I never new existed. Bravo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery can help you?

> Live Query utilizes the power of jQuery selectors by binding events or firing callbacks for matched elements auto-magically, even after the page has been loaded and the DOM updated.
>
> For example you could use the following code to bind a click event to all A tags, even any A tags you might add via AJAX.

```js
    $('a') 
      .livequery('click', function(event) { 
        alert('clicked'); 
        return false; 
    });
```